# same Image not store more then one time in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-activity, android-sqlite, android-bitmap

I am developing an android application, in which I am getting a single image from a URL and then store it into Sq lite database.

Currently the same image (Abc.png) store in sq lite database more then one time when I launch the Activity again and again ... I want that Same Image (Abc.png) not store more then one time.

How can i stop the same image (Abc.png) by storing it in database, when there is no row present in the database after that.

How can i do this...?

Here is my code :-

PanoramaViewActivity

```
public class PanoramaViewActivity extends Activity {

// Set your Image URL into a string
String URL = "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/17287086.jpg";
ImageView image, imagetop;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

private ImageDbAdapter mDbAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.panoramaview);

    // Locate the ImageView in activity_main.xml
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
    imagetop = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgtop);

    // Execute DownloadImage AsyncTask
    new DownloadImage().execute(URL);

}

// DownloadImage AsyncTask
private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PanoramaViewActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {
        String imageURL = URL[0];
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            // Download Image from URL
            InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
            // Decode Bitmap
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // Set the bitmap into ImageView
        image.setImageBitmap(result);
        // Close progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        insertToDB(result);
        queryFromDB();
    }
}

private void insertToDB(Bitmap result1) {
    mDbAdapter = new ImageDbAdapter(this);
    mDbAdapter.open();
    Bitmap photo = result1;
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    byte[] bArray = bos.toByteArray();
    mDbAdapter.insert(bArray);
}

private void queryFromDB() {
    byte[] image = mDbAdapter.fetchSingle(1);
    imagetop.setImageBitmap(Utilities.getImage(image));
    Log.d("result", "" + mDbAdapter.fetchSingle(1));
    mDbAdapter.close();
}
}
```

Utilities class :-

```
public class Utilities {
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
}
```

ImageDbHelper

```
public class ImageDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DB_NAME = "image_storage.db";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private static final String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE tbl_image ("
        + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "image_data BLOB"
        + ");";

private static final String SQL_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_image;";

public ImageDbHelper(Context c) {
    super(c, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}

}
```

ImageDbAdapter

```
public class ImageDbAdapter {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "tbl_image";
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_DATA = "image_data";

public static final String[] PROJECTION_ALL = new String[] { COL_ID,
        COL_DATA };

private Context mContext;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
private ImageDbHelper mDbHelper;

public ImageDbAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public ImageDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new ImageDbHelper(mContext);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public long insert(byte[] image) {
    return mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, createContentValues(image));
}

private ContentValues createContentValues(byte[] image) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COL_DATA, image);
    return cv;
}

public byte[] fetchSingle(int id) {
    Cursor queryCursor = mDb.query(TABLE_NAME, PROJECTION_ALL, COL_ID
            + " = " + id, null, null, null, null);
    if (queryCursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    byte[] image = null;
    if (queryCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        image = queryCursor.getBlob(queryCursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(COL_DATA));
    }
    queryCursor.close();
    return image;
}
}
```

Comment: Best option is to add one more coloum in you db table contain image name, insert image name when you are storing blob file ... check every time with image name that exist in db or not.

Comment: This is good idea...but How can i check image with image name in databse. when app is launch

Comment: you are getting image from this link right : String URL = "http://mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/17287086.jpg";  17287086.jpg is your image name

Comment: yes..and i am storing this image in database.... image store in database.. but every time this process work..and a single image store in database more thenone time... I want that this image store only one time when first time activity launch then every time its comes from databse not server

Comment: yes buddy that what i am saying to you is obtain image name from URL write method that will check image exist in db table ....if image exists do load from DB if not call your download sync Simple

Comment: is my answer helpful ??

Comment: yaa your answer is helpful... but how can i get image name?

Answer (score 0):

```
String URL ="mw2.google.com/mw-panoramio/photos/medium/17287086.jpg"

String[] bits = URL .split("/");

String imagename = bits[bits.length - 1];

System.out.println(imagename);

Result will be  17287086.jpg
```